# Creating a struct during while loop skips over input

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a struct and collect its inputs from the user with a while loop, however on the second iteration it just seems to skip past the inputs.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct Student {
    std::string name;
    std::string course;
    float mark;
};

int main() {

    std::list<Student> students;

    while (students.size() < 2) {
        Student student;

        std::cout << "Student Name:" << std::endl;
        std::getline (std::cin, student.name);
        std::cout << "Course and Mark:" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> student.course >> student.mark;

        students.push_back(student);
    }

    for(auto const& student: students) {
        std::cout << student.name << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like so:

```
Student Name:
Ari Stackoverflow
Course and Mark:
course543 56.2
Student Name:   <---- skipped :(
Course and Mark:
Steve Jobs
```

As you can see, one the second iteration it skips over getting the name, not sure why.

Comment: Try `std::cin >> student.name;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that when you press "Enter" after your second line of input, that newline is fed to `std::getline(std::cin, student.name);` on the next iteration. And so `students[1].name` would be an empty string.

To get around this, add `std::cin.ignore()` or `std::cin.get()` after reading your second line. This tells `cin` to ignore the newline.

Comment: This worked thank you! I still don't entirely understand it however, will need to experiment some more.